# Ajax Function Only Working Part of the Time

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am using the following Ajax function format:

```
var xmlhttp;

function addAddress(str)
{
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else
  {
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
  {
     if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
     {
       //specific selection text
       document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText; 
     }
  }
  var addAddress = "add";
  xmlhttp.open("POST", "sys.php", true);
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  var queryString = "&addAddress=" + addAddress;
  xmlhttp.send(queryString);
}

function GetXmlHttpObject()
{
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
    return new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
 if (windows.ActiveXObject)
  {
    return new ActiveXObject("Micorsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
 return null;
}
```

Up until now, all of my Ajax functions, like the one above, have been running fine.  However, now the function will work only sometimes.  Now, sometimes I will have to click the onclick event a couple times to execute the function or the function will just hang, and then after about 4 minutes it will execute.

I tested parts of the function and found that the issue lies some where at the:

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
 {
    alert(xmlhttp.status);
   //specific selection text
   document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText; 
 }
```

When the function works, I can alert(xmlhttp.status) and get 200.  However, when it's not working, the alert box doesn't even trigger.  In fact, nothing happens, not even an error.

Could this be a server issue?  I am kind of thinking my website got hacked, but I cannot find any issues accept that the Ajax functions are not executing properly.

Lastly, I do not get this problem on my localhost, it's only happening on the live website.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried not making your request variable global? Put `var xmlhttp;` inside the `addAddress` function and see what happens...

Comment: Hi andbeyond, thanks for the suggestion.  I just tried, but no luck.  I did add a alert(xmlhttp.status) in the if (window.XMLHttpRequest) and found that when the function hangs for a few minutes, the alert comes back with 0.

Comment: Also, the functions (website) work perfectly on my localhost. The problem only happens on the live website.

Comment: The way you have it set up in the code above, your alert will only trigger when the ajax request finishes (`readyState == 4`) and the server returns the `OK` status (`status == 200`). You may want to try `alert(xmlhttp.status)` outside of that `if` branch to see what you get. I expect the server is returning something other than `200`, like `404` or `500`... You can also look at the Net panel of the Firebug plugin for Firefox to help diagnose these types of issues.

Answer (score 1):

First just confirm that the addAddress function is actually being called when you click the button or control that should trigger it.

Just a simple alert in the first line like this would work:

```
function addAddress(str)
{
    alert('addAddress has been called!')
    ....
}
```

If you don't get the alert, make sure there isn't a javascript error on the page that is preventing the function from running.   In firefox you press CTRL+SHIFT+J to see the error console for example.

If that part is working, trying putting the URL for the ajax request directly into your browser and diagnose it that way.

Looks like you are requesting this url with ajax:

```
sys.php&addAddress= (address goes here)
```

Check that the page will load directly in your browser.  If not, the problem is not the ajax request, but something with the sys.php page itself - which you can then drill down on.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for the suggestions.  The function execution alert works every time and also an alert(queryString) at the bottom of the function works every time.  It looks like its as to do with the readystate or status.  I will try your other suggestions too.

Comment: Also, the functions (website) work perfectly on my localhost.  The problem only happens on the live website.

Answer (score 0):

This wasn't the answer I was expecting, but I ended up having my web host (GoDaddy) change servers, and that resolved the problem.  For almost a year, I was running IIS7 with PHP.  Since I had never run into any problems, I just continued using that server.  After the Ajax latency issue and not being able to figure out a solution, I figured I would just switch over to Apache.  After the change, everything started running smoothly again.

I am thinking maybe there was a software update that I was not notified about.  Or, maybe my website was getting hit with a DDoS, which was decreasing the performance of my Ajax requests.  Lastly, maybe someone got into IIS and changed a setting.  I don't know, all I know is that the minute the server was changed over to Apache was when the website started running normally again.

Thanks for everyone's suggestions.